# Openbox screen timeout

Tags: linux, vlc

I just install Openbox WM and I've config everything.
Then I watch movies with VLC. When I watching, every 10min the screen turned off, then I have to move my mouse to make it on again. I think, its problem with screen timeout. My question, how can I make my screen always on when I launch VLC?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is DPMS (Display Power Management System).
I make a script to turn off DPMS when playing movies.